# Autocompletion with qcompleter for fragments in the middle of a word

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qcombobox

Is there an example available of a `QCompleter` subclass that will provide autocompletions for fragments that appear in the middle of words?

eg:

Suppose you have the `wordlist { "apple", "pear", "banana" }`.
When the user types `'p'`, the suggested autocompletions should be `"apple"` and `"pear"`, but not banana (because `"apple"` and `"pear"` both contain `'p'`); 
The default autocompletion will only suggest `"pear"`.

Comment: In case you've found a solution to this I'd like to hear it. :)

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/23518-How-to-change-completion-rule-of-QCompleter?s=70013f5240656930018beef7d48dea28

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129211/) is similar enough to yours to help you.

Comment: I put a solution in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440173/2156909

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator 1.3 (that will be release soon) will have an extended completion that will allow to find a function by indicating only capital letter. See the video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TyfO-7lvy_c&feature=player_embedded.

This is a behavior near to the one you want. Since QtCreator is open source you can have a look to its [source code](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) for a real example. For now I do not know the release date of this version so you will have to wait a little to see.