# Search Filter in QTreeview Pyside

Tags: python, filtering, pyside, qtreeview

I have a working sample below that adds the search filter functionality. I feel like how I'm doing it is overkill. It was pieced together from projects I've found online. Do i really have to create this entire SearchProxyFilter to do a simple string filtering search on my list of items?

I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong or more than i need to. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

```
#######
# Imports
#######
import sys
import os
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

#######
# Main
#######
class SortModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SortModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pattern = ''

    @property
    def pattern(self):
        return self._pattern

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        if not self.pattern:
            return True

        sm = self.sourceModel()
        modelIdx = sm.index(sourceRow, 0)
        if modelIdx.isValid():
            txt = modelIdx.data(role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            if not self.pattern.lower() in txt.lower():
                return False

        return True

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
        rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)

        if leftData:
            leftData = leftData.lower()
        if rightData:
            rightData = rightData.lower()

        return leftData < rightData

class UserBrowser(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UserBrowser, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Users')
        self.setModal(True)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.results = ''
        self.filepath = ''

        self.ui_search = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.ui_search.setPlaceholderText('Search...')

        self.source_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.user_model = SortModel(self)
        self.user_model.setSourceModel(self.source_model)
        self.user_model.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.user_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.ui_items = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.ui_items.setModel(self.user_model)
        self.ui_items.setAlternatingRowColors(False)
        self.ui_items.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.ui_items.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.ui_items.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_items.header().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui_items.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.ui_items.setRootIsDecorated(False)

        gdl = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        gdl.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        gdl.addWidget(self.ui_search, 0, 0)
        gdl.addWidget(self.ui_items, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(gdl)
        self.create_model()

        self.ui_search.textChanged.connect(self.changed_text)

    # Methods
    def create_model(self):
        model = self.source_model
        model.clear()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Names'])

        users = ['kevin','Marry','Doug','Leslie','Michelle','John']
        for x in users:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setData(x , role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            model.appendRow(item)

        self.ui_items.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

    # Actions
    def changed_text(self, text):
        self.user_model._pattern = text
        self.user_model.invalidateFilter()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = UserBrowser()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done much more simply with a [QCompleter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html):

```
class UserBrowser(QtGui.QDialog):
    ...    
    def initUI(self):
        ...
        self.completer = QtGui.QCompleter(self)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.completer.setModelSorting(
            QtGui.QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)

        self.ui_items = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.ui_items.setModel(self.completer.completionModel())
        ...
        self.create_model()
        ...    
        self.ui_search.textChanged.connect(self.completer.setCompletionPrefix)

    # Methods
    def create_model(self):
        users = ['kevin','Marry','Doug','Leslie','Michelle','John']
        users.sort(key=str.lower)
        self.completer.setModel(QtGui.QStringListModel(users))
```

Comment: I felt like i was over complicating things. Thank you :)

Comment: is it possible to have the search look the text is 'in' rather than 'starts with'

Comment: @JokerMartini. Yes - but you'll probably end back where you started if you try to implement it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5129211/984421), for example. Unfortunately, I can't see any easy way to override the default filtering mechanism that `QCompleter` uses. There is [setFilterMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#filterMode-prop), which does exactly what you want - but it is Qt5 only.